# Can one use in a DLL, an external function that is provided by the main application instead of exporting DLL functions to the application?

Tags: c

e.g. In a static library I had

```
  void function (void);

  function();
```

And function() existed in the main application.

But If I build it as a DLL the linker complains that the function is undefined on the DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but this is hackish.

In the dll :

```
typedef void(*funcPtr)(void);
// Declare a variable named "ptrFunction" which is a pointer to a function which takes void as parameter and returns void
funcPtr ptrFunction;
// setter for ptrFunction; will be called from the .exe
void DLL_EXPORT setFunction(funcPtr f){ptrFunction f;}
// You can now use function() through ptrFunction
foo(){
   ptrFunction();
}
```

and you call setFunction from the .exe.

```
void function(){
    // implementation here
}    
int main(){
    setFunction(&function);  // now the dll knows the adress of function()
    foo(); // calls foo() in dll, which calls function() in the .exe
    ....
}
```

Great, huh ? :/
You should probably refactor your code so that function() is in yet another DLL, but it depends.

Comment: typedef line returns  error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token. on 15

Comment: @Lela Dax: I think Calvin1602 meant `typedef void(*funcPtr)(void);`.

Comment: @Charles: Sorry, corrected. @Lela : f is the adress of the function() that is implemented in the .exe. See edit.

Comment: I don't think that either `* f` is correct. In the parameter declaration `funcPtr` is already a pointer to a function so only `funcPtr f` is necessary. In the function body I assume that `ptrFunction * f;` should be `ptrFunction = f;`.

In the .exe code `function` needs to return void.

Comment: correct, but I don't get the "In the .exe code function needs to return void"

Comment: I meant that `function(){` isn't valid C (any more - it used to imply and implicit `int` return type), it should be `void function(){`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but I would strongly recommend against it if you don't have to. It's fiddly and it feels like you need to sort out your dependencies better.

To do it, you have to use `LIB.EXE` to create an import library from the object files of one binary before you actually link it; use this import library to link other binary and create an import library for the other binary; finally use the other library's import library to link the original binary.

E.g.

exe.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __declspec(dllimport) dllfn(void);

void __declspec(dllexport) exefn(void)
{
    puts("Hello, world!");
}

int main(void)
{
    dllfn();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler with `cl /c exe.c`. `exe.obj` is created.

exe.def:

```
LIBRARY exe.exe
```

Create import library with `lib /def:exe.def exe.obj`. `exe.lib` and `exe.exp` are created.

dll.c:

```
void __declspec(dllimport) exefn(void);

void __declspec(dllexport) dllfn(void)
{
    exefn();
}
```

Compile with `cl /c dll.c`. `dll.obj` is created.

Link DLL with `link /dll dll.obj exe.lib`. `dll.dll`, `dll.lib` and `dll.exp` are created.

Link EXE with `link exe.obj dll.lib`. `exe.exe` is created. (`exe.lib` and `exe.exp` are also recreated.)

Run exe, note the `Hello, world!` output.